# What happen if set SQL connection object = null

Tags: .net, ado.net

What happens when we set SQL connection object to null without closing connection.
 SQL server still hold connection? With whom?

I have search lot about this but haven't found answer

Comment: You leak connections.  It is never communicated to the server side to close the connection.  Null is not sufficient.  It's a two sided conversation.

Comment: @duffymo what about disposed it close connection?

Comment: Closed connection is the right thing.  Let the GC clean it up OR return it to your connection pool.

Comment: @AdamV We have made one more layer for it and we have lots of things to do in single transaction

Comment: As the SqlConnection object is Disposable, you should use it. The Dispose  will cleanup the resources and close the connection.

Comment: There should only be one layer.  Services own transactions; they can commit or rollback multiple requests as a single unit of work.

Comment: here what going to happen. Your connection object will hang on the background (to make it clear that it will be there but you can't access it again). And it will be there in open state. Once this is "achieved", one of the following will happen, it will be disconnected by connection pool trying to reclaim connections or it will be closed and object will be destroyed during garbage collection. But no one can tell when these things will happen as far as time frame. This is why you use `using(var conn = ....){...}`. This guarantees that connection will close even if you don't say `conn.Close()`

Answer (score 1):

When you are setting the connection object/reference to null,

```
Connection conn = null;
```

the reference to the connection object is deleted in this case as the connection is in open state so it will be open and your resource will not be free.

**If you don't close the connection, you can have a connection leak. It is important to close the connection in a finally block.**

Answer (score 1):

No sql server will not be hold the connection, when you will write Connection conn = null, it will remove object address from stack but heap still hold the value of his object.so it will increase leaked memory because memory is still occupying by heap.

Comment: So if I assign assign null it will removed from connection pull??

Comment: @umeshsohaliya Look at my comment above. What else do you need to know?

Comment: When ever execution will complete or process will complete it will flush all the connection. If application/Process is still running it will hold connection in database.

Comment: @T.S. I completely agree with you. I am ok with this.